# C# get smallest and largest values from a list

Tags: c#, list

I need to go through a list and find the largest and smallest values. The list is populated based on the input from a user entering information into a form text box. Then each time that I click on a button to calculate in my form it runs code that does calculations and puts decimals into listProfit.
I have looked all over the place and tried using .Sort() but that causes a system error.

This is the error I am getting.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Collection was
>   modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

error highlights the "in" in my foreach loop.

```
//list of each order total
List<decimal> listProfit = new List<decimal>(); 

    foreach(int item in listProfit)
                    {
                        listProfit.Sort();
                        decimal smallest = listProfit[0];
                        decimal largest = listProfit[listProfit.Count - 1];
                        SmallTxt.Text = smallest.ToString("c");
                        LargestTxt.Text = largest.ToString("c");
                    }
```

Comment: Why are you sorting the collection on every iteration? That seems like a very bad idea to me. Why are you iterating at all, after sorting? What is the full stack trace? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Sorting the list each time because new values are being entered each time that I run the calculations.

Comment: @CodyMoser: `"new values are being entered each time"` - Um, no there aren't.  Nothing in that loop adds an element to the collection.  Where in that loop do you *think* an element is being added?  It doesn't even really make sense to me why you have a loop in the first place.  Or why you're trying to find values from *an empty list*.  The intent behind this code is confusing at best.

Answer (score 11):

Use `Min` and `Max` from System.Linq:

```
var min = listProfit.Min();
var max = listProfit.Max();
```

Comment: When I do what you suggested i receive and error. An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: Sequence contains no elements

Comment: @CodyMoser: Well, according to your code, you have an empty list.  There *is no* minimum or maximum value.  Because there are no values at all.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to iterate at all. You can just say like below, if you want to continue with sorting the list. Else, try using `Min()` and `Max()` LINQ extension methods to get those directly

```
  listProfit.Sort();
  decimal smallest = listProfit[0];
  decimal largest = listProfit[listProfit.Count - 1];
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the minimum value use

```
SmallTxt.text = listProfit.Min().ToString("c");
```

To get the max

```
LargestTxt.Text = listProfit.Max().ToString("c");
```

No need to sort the list, however be aware that both of these operations enumerate the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I am assuming you are a beginner. Consider [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and think how you would do this without LINQ.

```
// declare list
var listProfit = new List<decimal>(); 
// populate list 
listProfit.Add(300.5m); //etc

// initial values for min and max
decimal min = Decimal.MaxValue;
decimal max = Decimal.MinValue;

// loop through the list
for (int i = 0; i < listProfit.Count; i++)
{
    // is the current item smaller than min? 
    if (listProfit[i] < min) 
        // if yes, set min to that value
        min = listProfit[i];
    // is the current value greater than max?
    if (listProfit[i] > max) 
        // if yes, set max to that value
        max = listProfit[i];
}

// you are now outside of the for loop, with your min and max values populated
```

If you're sorting the list beforehand, @Rahul's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

Please see [Input form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXPzg.png)

```
 List<decimal> lstProfit = new List<decimal>();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstProfit.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text));

        textBox2.Text = lstProfit.Min().ToString();
        textBox3.Text = lstProfit.Max().ToString();
    }
```

Please see [input/output form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPSkz.png)

[explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=469ANuy4WRI)